# Deferred foreign key 'OrderPayment.order' has not been mapped

Tags: python, django, django-shop

I'm trying to integrate django-shop with a simple django installation but it gives my following error :

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Deferred foreign key 'OrderPayment.order' has not been mapped
```

I even tried creating the OrderPayment model as referred in docs as below but still I got no luck.

```
class OrderPayment(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
order = models.ForeignKey(on_delete=models.deletion.CASCADE, to=Order, verbose_name='Order')

class Meta():
    verbose_name = "Order Payment"
```

Answer (score 2):

You either have to implement your materialized models first or to import the defaults models in your shop implementation. See this link: http://django-shop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/deferred-models.html

Edit:
The defaults models are located in the shop/models/defaults directory. You can either import them in your shop implementation or copy them and modify them to fit your project needs.

shop/models/defaults/__init__.py says:

> The models in directory default have been added as a pure convenience
>   and for demonstration purpose. Whenever there is a need to use a
>   modified version, copy one of these models into the projects model
>   directory and adopt it to your needs. Otherwise just import the model
>   into your own models.py file without using it. The latter is important
>   to materialize the model.
>
> Each model is declared in its own file. This is to prevent model
>   validation errors on related fields if a file containing this
>   definition is imported without using the model.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give a bit of code to demonstrate the correct usage and the incorrect usage, even if it's all in the link. Links can be fragile.

Comment: I have edited my answer. No code example is needed. But you are right about the links expiration.